# Rate of Increase of Area of Circle / Volume of Sphere

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives, related-rates

The rate of change of area of a circle with respect to change in its radius is equal to its circumference, as shown below:
$$\frac{dA}{dr} = \frac{d}{dr}(\pi r^2) = 2\pi r$$

The rate of change of volume of a sphere with respect to change in its radius is equal to its surface area:
$$\frac{dV}{dr} = \frac{dV}{dr}(\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3) = 4\pi r^2$$

Is there a geometrical/mathematical explanation for this?

Comment: There should be '4πr^2' instead of '4πr' in the last expression

Comment: One reason could be that area of elemental ring in case of a circular disc is $dA=2\pi r dr$ and in case of solid sphere volume of elemental shell is $dV=4\pi r^2 dr$